# Unusual Looped Macro Behaviour

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which executes a macro on all sheets in my Workbook, with the exception of those in the excludesheets string.

The weird thing is, it's ignoring other sheets as well, with no logic behind it.

Home Page, Overview and Setup are at the front then I have 18 sheets which I want executing and then Original, Metrics, Overview old and Teams to be finally excluded.

All the string sheets are being skipped but 9 of my desired sheets are too.

Can anyone help?

```
Sub Error_Check()

Const excludeSheets As String = "Home Page,Overview,Setup,Original,Metrics,Overview old,Teams"

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Sheets
ws.Activate

If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Split(excludeSheets, ","))) Then

'Macro bit

End If


Next ws

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your `Match` statement needs to have the `match_type` parameter specified as you've left it blank.

Try this instead (notice the 0):

```
If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Split(excludeSheets, ","),0)) Then
```

This parameter specifies whether the exact value is matched or largest for example. See from the MS docs:

> If match_type is 1, MATCH finds the largest value that is less than or equal to lookup_value.
>
> If match_type is 0, MATCH finds the first value that is exactly equal to lookup_value. Lookup_array can be in any order.
>
> If match_type is -1, MATCH finds the smallest value that is greater than or equal to lookup_value.
>
> If match_type is omitted, it is assumed to be 1.

Comment: Excellent. Simple as that. Thank you Gareth, I wasn't ware of the parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `Application.Match` try using `InStr`. This function tells you the position of a given substring within a string. *However*: `InStr` returns 0 if the specified substring is not found, making it another easy solution to your problem without the need for `Split()`.

Instead of your

```
If IsError([...]) Then
```

try this:

```
Const excludeSheets = "/Home Page/Overview/Setup/Original/Metrics/Overview old/Teams/"
[...]
If InStr(excludeSheets, "/" & ws.Name & "/") = 0 Then
```

Personally I find this approach more concise and readable and you can also easily reverse the logic simply by changing the comparison operator from `=` to `>` to iterate *only* on worksheets whose names are in excludeSheets. I used forward slashes as delimiters since they're illegal characters in worksheet names whereas commas are not.

Comment: Another interesting take on the solution and one to put in my tool kit. Thanks Aiken.